# Why does macOS keep asking me to configure a Recovery Contact?

Tags: macos, security, data-recovery

Recently macOS has started asking me repeatedly to configure a Recovery Contact. But I already have one configured. In fact I recently deleted and re-added my Recovery Contacts in an effort to convince macOS that I have some already, to on avail.

Why does macOS keep asking me to configure a Recovery Contact, when I already have some? What do I need to do to convince Apple that I have already done what it is asking? Or is there something more to adding a Recovery Contact than just adding a Recovery Contact?

Comment: Try signing out of your iCloud account on your Mac and log back in.